# How to register custom components in Vue3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm using the [ionicons](https://ionic.io/ionicons) library in my Vue project but I get this warning in the console:

```
Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: ion-icon. 
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.
```

I tried configuring my `vue.config.js` like [this poster](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/yarnpkg-where-to-set-compileroptions/125040/7) but it hasn't worked for me. This is my `vue.config.js` at the moment:

```js
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('vue')
      .use('vue-loader')
      .tap(options => {
        options['compilerOptions'] = {
          ...options.compilerOptions || {},
          isCustomElement: tag => tag === 'ion-icon'
        };
        return options;
      })
  }
})
```

Comment: Please check this https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/using-ionicons-in-ionic-vue-3/198172/6

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have the following `<script>` tags in your `public/index.html`:

> ```
>  <script type="module" 
>  src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"> 
>  </script>
>  <script nomodule 
>  src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
> ```

Try adding this line in your main.js, as this will ignore all components with an `ion-` prefix:

```
Vue.config.ignoredElements = [/^ion-/]
```

Take a look at: https://dev.to/devmount/how-to-use-ionicons-v5-with-vue-js-53g2

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, that article is outdated, so the advice doesn't work. I did import the script tags into index.html, and the icons work -- I'm just trying to find a way to get rid of the warning because they spam my console.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the answer you looking for? Usually I meet this warning just add the component and the warn will be fixed. **write on your vue page**

```
import {IonIcon} from '@ionic/vue';
export default defineComponent({
  compontents:{
   IonIcon
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In vite.config.js you need to add this into ' plugins[]' (in my case I used 'v-list-item-icon':

```js
vue({ 
    template: { 
        transformAssetUrls,
        compilerOptions: {
            isCustomElement: (tag) => ['v-list-item-icon'].includes(tag),
       
        }
    }
}),
```